# CREATESTRUCT pointer is not equivalent to first element of struct

Tags: c, winapi

Using CREATESTRUCT object from lParam parameter from WindowProc function called by CreateWindowEx results in strange behavior regarding location of lpCreateParams element.

```
CREATESTRUCT* pCreate = (CREATESTRUCT*) lParam;
printf("%lld ", ((size_t)pCreate->lpCreateParams) - (size_t)pCreate);
//1712 on my machine
```

Based on windowsAPI [reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/ns-winuser-createstructa), lpCreateParams should be the first element of the struct and therefore should be equivalent to the struct pointer. Does this mean that CREATESTRUCT has different implementations depending on platform ?

Edit: I am using gcc version 13.2.0 (x86_64-win32-seh-rev1, Built by MinGW-Builds project) and compiling using `gcc -g -municode --all-warnings -O3 file.c -lpthread -o file -lgdi32`

Comment: The code block that I described in the question (difference between pCreate and pCreate->lpCreateParams). The expected output is 0, as the pointers are expected to be identical. The actual result is 1712, meaning that pCreate->lpCreateParams pointer is actually 1712 bytes in memory ahead of pCreate pointer. EDIT: Comment I was responding to was removed, it was something like "What code outputs 1712 and what is the expected value"

Comment: Not sure why pointer arithmetic didn't work as expected there.   Here is an option that does work as expected... [please have a look](https://godbolt.org/z/6fqbeqs74).   Can't post as an answer because I lack the expertise to say why your 1st try doesn't work, and community would strongly object to such an 'answer', I think.

Comment: `lpCreateParams` is a pointer that might point to anything, if you want the **address** of `lpCreateParams` you need `((size_t)&pCreate->lpCreateParams)`.

Comment: @gregspears I tried your solution and it does indeed come out to be zero, but when I replaced the definition of CREATESTRUCT with a malloc(5000), the output difference gets even stranger (14976 on my machine).

Comment: @JonathanPotter, thanks, this was indeed the case. Solved

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As pointed out by @JonathanPotter in the comments, `lParam->lpCreateParams` is itself a pointer value, so to get the address of it (its position in the struct), using `&lParam->lpCreateParams` is required.

`((size_t)&pCreate->lpCreateParams) - (size_t)pCreate)` returns the expected result.

Comment: Excellent. You can accept your answer for guidance.